# How to add text in a rectangle to a pdf

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, pdf-generation, core-graphics

I am generating a pdf with certain format in which I placed a rectangular box with the help of the below code...

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGPathRef path = CGPathCreateWithRect(CGRectMake(40, rectPosition, 540, 150), NULL);
[[UIColor whiteColor] setFill];

//[[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];

CGContextAddPath(context, path);
CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);
CGPathRelease(path);
```

I achieve it but now I want to set the text inside the rectangle and I tried `drawRect` method and many other... Do help if anyone knows.

Comment: - (void)drawText:(CGFloat)xPosition yPosition:(CGFloat)yPosition canvasWidth:(CGFloat)canvasWidth canvasHeight:(CGFloat)canvasHeight This is the method which is used for writing inside the rectangular frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)drawText:(CGFloat)xPosition yPosition:(CGFloat)yPosition canvasWidth:(CGFloat)canvasWidth canvasHeight:(CGFloat)canvasHeight
{
//Here you Can Write whatever you want to add in the rectangle
}
```